# VSTS RIG Setup configuration - Agent Machine in "Disconnected" Status

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

Im using VSTS controller agent setup to run a load test of a Web Application. I have 3 machines configured for this RIG setup. My machine (MACHINE 1) is configured as one Controller. Apart from my machine, I have another controller machine (MACHINE 2) and one Agent machine (MACHINE 3).

I'm giving the control from my machine (MACHINE 1) to another controller machine (MACHINE 2) where the agent machine (MACHINE 3) is been added. I can see the agent machine and the controller machine added to my controller machine.

The problem is that, the agent machine in the "Agent Pane" through visual studio "Manage Test Controller" menu in DISCONNECTED. How can I make it to "Online" so that I can run the load test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same question in the MSDN forum where I got certain aspects that I have to check while configuring the RIG-controller and agent setup. With the help of the reply's in the MSDN forum I have make the RIG setup work. Can refer the following link if you too are facing the problem as I did.

[Aspects to be checked while Configuring VSTS RIG Setup](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstswebtest/thread/efe6ce2c-19d8-4402-9b8a-1dda4780d756)